# Est-ce que le mot « internaute » est souvent utilisé?

Tags: usage, néologismes

J'ai trouvé dans quelques articles le mot « [internaute](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internaute) » pour les gens qui utilisent l'internet, similaire à astronaute. En anglais, le mot analogue « [internaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internaut) » est utilisé uniquement par un petit groupe de geeks, jamais par le public.

Il me semble que le terme français est assez courant, contrairement à la forme anglaise ; est-ce que c'est vrai ? Ou existe-t-il un mot différent qui est utilisé plus fréquemment ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C'est en effet un mot qui me semble passé dans l'usage commun, ni réservé aux adversaires acharnés du franglais (comme certaines francisations peuvent l'être), ni à un groupe restreint d'initiés.

Comment: En fait, c'est devenu le terme officiel pour désigner les utilisateurs d'Internet.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, *internaute* est énormément utilisé. Le marketing pousse ce terme notamment dans les publicités pour les fournisseurs d'accès à Internet.

Comment: La presse a énormément contribué à la promotion de ce terme, elle aussi. Particulièrement dans les années 1995/2000 pour autant que je me souvienne.

Comment: Les FAI ont tenté aussi de s'approprier le terme avec des formes de type _MARQUE-naute_, heureusement sans succès.

Answer (score 4):

À mon avis, *internaute* n'a pas eu trop de mal à s'imposer pour les raisons suivantes : ce n'est pas un mot anglais à la base, et il n'y a pas réellement de mot anglais répandu pour exprimer la même idée. Il est d'ailleurs amusant de voir que l'équivalent *internaut* ne perce pas réellement — peut-être parce qu'il est perçu comme venant du français?

<strike>Comme ce n'est pas un terme anglais à la base, et qu'il n'y a pas réellement de terme anglais équivalent,</strike>

Comment: Il me semble que tu n'as pas fini ta

Comment: Tiens, c'est bi